# Using .stepUp() with JQuery returns error ".stepUp is not a function"

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

See example on codepen here: https://codepen.io/Rubenkretek/pen/VwYQVgO?editors=1111

Expected result:
The input field increments by 1 when clicking the '+' button.

Actual result:
No changes to input and following error:

> TypeError: selectedInput.stepUp is not a function

```js
$(function() {

  $('<span class="add" uk-icon="plus">+</span>').insertAfter('.product-container .product-quantity input');
  $('<span class="sub" uk-icon="minus">-</span>').insertBefore('.product-container .product-quantity input');


  $('.add').click(function() {

    var selectedInput = $(this).prev('input');

    if (selectedInput.val() < 10) {
      console.log("value is less than 10");
      $('.add').click(function() {
        selectedInput.stepUp(1);
      });
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-info">
    <h2>Product name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product-quantity">
    <input type="number"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have nested event handlers. Only have on click event handler and delegate it

Comment: Is there a reason for having multiple click handlers on the same element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nesting event handlers. Only have one and delegate

Also the stepUp is a DOM method so you need to get the DOM element from the jQuery (adding [0] to the element)

NOTE: The type=number has its own spinner controls

UPDATE: I realised looking at the question, that there likely would be more than one qty field in the div

```js
$(function() {
  $('<span class="add" uk-icon="plus">+</span>').insertAfter('.product-container .product-quantity input');
  $('<span class="sub" uk-icon="minus">-</span>').insertBefore('.product-container .product-quantity input');

  $('.product-quantity').on("click", '.add, .sub', function() {
    let dir = $(this).is(".add");
    // use bracket notation to get .prev() or .next() 
    // and then [0] to get the DOM element because stepUp is a DOM method
    const selectedInput = $(this)[dir ? "prev" : "next"]()[0]; 
    let val = +selectedInput.value || 0;
    const min = +selectedInput.min;
    const max = +selectedInput.max;
    if ((dir && val < 10) ||
      (!dir && val > 0)) {
      selectedInput.stepUp(dir ? 1 : -1);
    } else console.log("Value needs to be between", min, " and ", max)
  });
});
```

```css
[type=number] {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-info">
    <h2>Product name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product-quantity">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" /><br />
    <input type="number" min="0" max="5" value="0" /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, having two event handlers was a mistake, I have since fixed it and the only way to make it work was to change `selectedInput.stepUp(1);` to `selectedInput[0].stepUp(1);`. Would you be able to explain why that is?

Comment: Yes, as I did in my comment above, after `find('input')[0];`. It is the DOM representation. There is no stepUp in jQuery